# How do I use hadoop fs -getmerge to download .deflate files?

Tags: hadoop, compression

I've tried running

```
hadoop fs -getmerge
```

on a directory of .deflate files. The result is a **compressed** file on my local machine.

What is the easiest way to download the entire directory in **uncompressed** format on to my local machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
hadoop fs -text /some/where/job-output/part-*
```